# How to retrieve the GUID for Yahoo's Contacts API

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth

I'm attemping to use the Yahoo Contacts API to add an "invite your friends" feature on a site I'm building.

I've found the correct web service to call (`http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/{guid}/contacts`) but it is asking for the user's GUID, not their username/password.

I've searched, and am unable to find a "lookup" feature through the Yahoo API which lets me get the user's guid from their username/password.

Does anyone have any experience with the Contacts API.

I've reaad over the documentation, and looked at YQL as well, but I still haven't found how to get the user's guid.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from their developer documentation:

> To get the GUID of the user who is
>   running the application, call the GET
>   operation on the following URI. This
>   user must be signed in to Yahoo!
>
> ```
> URI:
>       http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/me/guid
> ```

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/rest_api_guide/introspective-guid-resource.html

Note that you can't login the user silently -- you need to display the Yahoo login page with a pop-up window and get an OAuth token (more info about this found in the dev docs).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still lost.  I find their documentation just horrible, either that or I'm just really stupid the last few days.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simply:

> http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/me/contacts

Answer (score 0):

First you need to signup your application to YDN. than you will get a consumer key and consumer secret to implement oAuth.When you get your application authorized by user.then  yahoo passes you a access token and GUID by which you can call yahoo's social api.

[check this out](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html)